# Workaround to lime-legacy not providing access to lime classes

Tags: haxe, openfl, lime-haxe, haxepunk

I'm using HaxePunk 2.5.6 with OpenFL 3.6.1 and Lime 2.9.1 ; I read in [an issue on the HaxeFlixel GitHub](https://github.com/HaxeFlixel/flixel-addons/issues/222) that Lime prevents access to its classes on legacy. That's a big problem, because HaxePunk uses legacy by default. I want to use `lime.ui.FileDialog` to open and save files, but since HaxePunk is stuck with legacy, obviously that doesn't work (`lime.ui.FileDialog` reads as `null` instead of `Class<lime.ui.FileDialog>` ...). Is there a workaround to this ? I didn't see anything in OpenFL that replaces this, so I'm really lost. Obviously I don't want to install any additional lib unless it's really necessary. Using `-Dnext` or `-Dhybrid` when compiling to override `-Dlegacy` breaks everything, so that's not a solution either.

Thanks by advance !

Comment: Upon further inspection, it appears that OpenFL implements the `openfl.net.FileReference` class, which is exactly what I need. Except guess what ? It's not implemented for `openfl-legacy` either, so welp, I'm still as stuck as before.

Answer (score 1):

You could go to `<haxelib directory>/lime/2,9,1/legacy` and undo the changes to `include.xml` in [the relevant commit](https://github.com/openfl/lime/commit/35b555f04af8af89dc4b765319d081d197d9a53d) by removing this line:

```
<haxeflag name="--macro" value="exclude('lime')" />
```

**However**, as described in [this thread](http://community.openfl.org/t/error-when-launching-game-in-windows/7217/52), this adds a dependency to `lime.ndll` (as opposed to `lime-legacy.ndll`, which is the only one being copied to `/bin` for legacy builds), so your binary would crash when shipped to other computers that don't have a Haxe installation.

You can work around this by manually copying `lime.ndll` over (or add `<ndll name="lime" dir="ndll" />` to legacy's `include.xml`), but using a third-party library like [systools](http://lib.haxe.org/p/systools/) or [linc_dialogs](https://github.com/snowkit/linc_dialogs) would be a cleaner solution.

Comment: I tried that, but HaxePunk programs don't compile then. I found out that I can use `-Dnext` in some cases, which fixes the issue, but this breaks something in HaxePunk that I'm not using in this project (still haven't found out what), so I'd rather do it the correct way. I saw systools, but the dialogs break on Linux it seems (there are a couple of issues about this that were never addressed) ; linc_dialogs only works with the C++ target, while that's not really a big deal (seeing the use I'll have for it), I like to retain maximum versatility. But then again, I guess I'll give it a try.

Comment: Well I am confused, I cannot get it to break again (which is sort of good news) ... I tried linc_dialogs though, I think I'll stick with it, I'm using it for a utility program so it doesn't really matter if I stick to the C++ target or not. Besides, I don't like to mess with libs' options and parameters, so I'm fine with linc_dialogs. Thanks for pointing that out !

Comment: Well, you _were_ asking for a workaround without additional dependencies. ;)

Comment: Yeah indeed. But I installed it and it's not given me any trouble, so let's say I'm fine with that :P